# Encountering error running custom actions in rasa

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I recently started working on rasa. My chatbot is simple. Whenever a user asks a question, the bot filters data from a `sqlite3` database and return the result. I added the training examples, created stories for flow, and wrote a custom action to filter data from the database. for the custom action, I specified an endpoint and started the action server. This is my code so far

## actions.py

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_core_sdk import Action, Tracker
import sqlite3

class TestAction(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_testAction"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        UserId = tracker.get_slot('UserID')
        query = 'SELECT User_name FROM sales WHERE UserID=?'

        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, (UserId,))
        name = cursor.fetchall()

        msg = 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
        dispatcher.utter_message(msg)
```

## endpoints.yml

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/"
```

for running the endpoint, I ran the following code in a separate terminal window

```
python -m rasa_sdk --actions actions
```

But when I run the program with `rasa shell --endpoints endpoints.yml` command based on this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985323/rasa-custom-actions-not-connected)**, I get the following error

```
rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_testAction'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
```

This is what my action endpoint server returned

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2019-09-09 11:07:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.005443
```

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong. I checked the code actions.py file. I dont seem to have made any errors there.

## [edit 1]

I was looking online and came across this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@bikashkumars/create-chatbot-using-rasa-part-1-67f68e89ddad).

In this tutorial, the endpoint is defined as

```
action_endpoint:   
    url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Now i tried the same with my code. when I run the chatbot with the updated code, I get the following exception in the action_server

```
Exception: No registered Action found for name 'action_testAction'.
```

## [edit 2]

results of running the actions server i debug mode

```
(base) SASHAANKs-MacBook-Pro:speechbot2 sashaanksekar$ rasa run actions -vv
2019-09-09 19:38:33 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2019-09-09 19:38:38 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)
2019-09-09 19:39:06 DEBUG    rasa_sdk.executor  - Received request to run 'action_testAction'
2019-09-09 19:39:06 ERROR    flask.app  - Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_sdk/endpoint.py", line 59, in webhook
    response = executor.run(action_call)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 246, in run
    "No registered Action found for name '{}'.".format(action_name)
Exception: No registered Action found for name 'action_testAction'.
```

Please help me

Comment: Try running the action server with `rasa run actions --actions actions -vv` inside the folder which contains the `actions.py` file. It doesn't seem to be picking up the TestAction class.

Comment: actions.py exists in the root directory. I am running the server from that directory. I also tried moving actions.py to its own folder. That does not work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `Exception: No registered Action found for name 'action_testAction'.` error is because of your first exception when running the action server i.e. because of this:

```
rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_testAction'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
```

Try running the action server in `debug mode` using the debug flag `-vv` like `rasa run actions -vv` to see where the problem in your code is. (The problem may be because you may not have imported Action or sqlite3 or whatever else).

Hope that helps.

Edit:

> Make sure that the name of the `action` file matches.

Running `rasa run actions --actions action -vv` yeilds

```
(chatbot) PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\rasa-test> python -m rasa_sdk --actions action -vv
2019-09-09 21:02:56 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server... 
2019-09-09 21:02:56 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_testAction'.
2019-09-09 21:02:56 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)
```

`action.py`

```
import sqlite3

from rasa_sdk import Action

class TestAction(Action):

    def name(self):
        return "action_testAction"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        UserId = tracker.get_slot('UserID')
        query = 'SELECT User_name FROM sales WHERE UserID=?'

        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, (UserId,))
        name = cursor.fetchall()

        msg = 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
        dispatcher.utter_message(msg)
```

Comment: I tried running the action server in debug mode. I was getting the same error. Also I have edited the question to add the imports in the actions.py file. Please take a look.

Comment: I had also posted the question in [rasa forums](https://forum.rasa.com/t/exception-no-registered-action-found-for-name-action-testaction/15406). The person asked me to create a new directory with `rasa init` and pasting the actions in the new directory. Still did not work

Comment: @Sashaank can you run the action server in debug mode and put the complete error message here? This problem is caused when the action is not found by the actions server. Also, can you try running the action server with `rasa run actions --actions actions`?

Comment: please check the question. I have added the results of debug mode. also running the server with `rasa run actions --actions actions` yields the same result

Comment: @Sashaank I've updated the answer to include what worked for me. When the action server finds custom actions, it should say sth like `Registered function for 'custom_action'`. i can't see this in your logs.

Comment: I dont understand what happened. I ran your code `rasa run actions --actions actions -vv`. But instead of `action` I used `actions` as before. And for some reason I thought of upgrading the rasa library. Now I am using version 1.2.7. It works now

Comment: the action file in the folder is actions.py

Comment: @Sashaank hmm... it may have been a compatibilty issue. https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#changed-2 states that `package renamed from rasa_core_sdk to rasa_sdk - please make sure to update your imports accordingly`. Maybe that caused the issue? Nice that it works now.

Comment: @Sashaank: Have you shared your action in domain.yml and in your story.md?

Comment: Yes I did. The program works after I upgraded the rasa library. I guess I had to run the proper version and ensure that the right actions.py is being called when starting the server

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the easy solution was to observe the error and code in this below part of the actions.py file.

```
class TestAction(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_testAction"
```

The name of the class is 'TestAction' and the return value of 'name' function is 'action_testAction'. So the error is - the name of the action you are using in domain file is not matching with the name returned by this 'name' method in this class. Use this 'action_testAction' in NLU training data and domain file.